# compiling java source code with ant

Tags: java, ant

I have a Java source code package which is known to successfully compile. I am attempting to compile the package with ant (the build.xml file is present). When I run ant all the Java import statements generate an error message of the type:

> The import java.awt.geom.Path2D cannot be resolved" (the specific message depends on what is being imported)

Clearly the package paths are not defined and I have no idea where the requested imports live in the filesystem. I assume if I know the paths that setting `$CLASSPATH` will get the program to compile. I am using opensuse 13.2 and my installed java info is:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone point me to where to find the java packages and how to get ant to compile the sources?

The command line used to compile sources is:
ant

build.xml is in the same directory that ant is run from which also contains the src directory. This is a working project, I just don't know how to configure standard library locations (I'm not a java type by any means).

Update.

I have located the path to the openjdk libraries at /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/lib/rt.jar and have tried to compile 2 different ways but still get imports cannot be resolved error messages.

Compiling with -lib option does not work:

ant -lib /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/lib/rt.jar

Setting the CLASSPATH environment variable does not work:

export CLASSPATH=/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/lib/rt.jar

ant

The content of build.xml is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="MazR" default="jar" basedir=".">
  <property name="jar.file" value="${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
  <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
  <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
  <property name="dist.dir" value="dist"/>
  <property name="applet.html" value="applet.html"/>

  <taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties"/>

  <target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="on"
           includeantruntime="false">
      <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
    </javac>
  </target>

  <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${jar.file}" basedir="${build.dir}">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.nullprogram.maze.RunMaze"/>
      </manifest>
    </jar>
    <copy file="${applet.html}" tofile="${dist.dir}/index.html"/>
  </target>

  <target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${dist.dir}/${jar.file}" fork="true"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <delete file="${jar.file}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="check">
    <checkstyle config="checkstyle.xml">
      <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java"/>
    </checkstyle>
  </target>

  <target name="format" description="Run the indenter on all source files.">
    <apply executable="astyle">
      <arg value="--mode=java"/>
      <arg value="--suffix=none"/>
      <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
    </apply>
  </target>

  <target name="applet" depends="jar" description="Run the applet version.">
    <exec executable="appletviewer">
      <arg value="${dist.dir}/index.html"/>
    </exec>
  </target>

  <target name="javadoc" description="Generate Javadoc HTML.">
    <javadoc destdir="${dist.dir}/javadoc">
      <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java" />
    </javadoc>
  </target>
</project>
```

Any idea why import does not seem to work?

Thanks!

Further update.

I added a classpath definition to the build.xml as below, still no joy. I have not used Java in many, many years so I am way out of my depth here, help desperately appreciated.

```html
  <property name="java.class.path" location="/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/lib/rt.jar"/>

  <target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="on"
           includeantruntime="false">
      <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
      <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}/"/>
      </classpath>
    </javac>
  </target>
```

Comment: maybe set $JAVA_HOME?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918959/import-cannot-be-resolved or instead, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664591/the-import-package-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: Please show the ant task specific to the compile (javac) as used by you. Also refer the [javac ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) and notice that you have 3 options top provide the classpath: 1. classpath attribute 2. classpath nested element 3. classpathref attribute

Comment: $JAVA_HOME is setup correctly. I am not using any IDE, just ANT from the command line using build.xml.

Comment: If you want help with the question "why does my build.xml not work" then you need to show us at least the relevant fragment of build.xml - the `<javac>` call and the definition of its classpath if it is referenced by a `classpathref`.  Setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable will not help, the classpath for a `javac` task in an Ant build is set by the build.xml

Comment: @Ian Roberts, thanks, tried defining the classpath in the build.xml. Didn't work, but no surprise as I am at the limit of my knowledge on the subject.

Comment: There should never be any need to include rt.jar explicitly on the class path as it is there by default as the core class library. Does it work if you simply remove the whole `<classpath>` element?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your javac and java symlinks are pointing at different places

Compare these two commands and see if they point into the roughly the same area:

```
which javac
which java
```

Comment: Thanks Trevor, which javac reports /usr/bin/javac, which java reports /usr/bin/java. Looking deeper, realpath /usr/bin/javac reports /usr/bin/gcj-4.8, realpath /usr/bin/java reports /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/bin/java. So I have the GCC Java compiler and the OpenJDK JRE, probably not good. Checking the package manager, the OpenJDK development tools are not installed. I'll install the OpenJDK development tools and report back. Thanks!